# c++ operation precedence bug in g++ compiler vs clang++ compiler

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-precedence, postfix-operator

the output of the code below are different between g++ and clang++ !
I think clang++ is correct, what do you think?

g++ output: `11 4 13 7`

clang++ output: `11 4 11 8`

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{ 
    int a; 
    A(int x): a{x}{}
    A  operator ++(int){ A temp = *this; ++a; return temp; }
    A& operator *(int x){ a*=x; return *this; }
    A& operator +(A& x){ a+=x.a; return *this; }
    operator int(){ return a; }
};
int main() 
{
    int myINT{3};
    int y = myINT++ + myINT * 2;
    std::cout << y << " " << myINT << '\n';

    A myA{3};
    y = myA++ + myA * 2;
    std::cout << y << " " << myA << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is undefined behavior to use the increment operator in such an expression. Clang should give you a warning about the "unsequenced modification and access to myInt" ([see live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1ra34j6a7)).

Comment: What is amazing is that why so many new programmers would want to do anything like this: `y = myA++ + myA * 2;`.  Even if this had defined behavior, why have such a confusing line of code written in this fashion?  The days of trying to stuff `++` and `+` on one line of code, just to "outdo the compiler's optimizer" are long gone.

Comment: Both are correct! You only know that the operator ++ is applied to `myInt` (id. for `myA`) after taking its value **in `myInt++`**, but whether it happens before or after taking the value of the other `myInt` operand is not specified by the language.

Comment: Precedence is not the issue. Precedence does say, for example, that `myINT++` and `myINT *2` are evaluated before their results are added together, but precedence does not go further into which gets evaluated first, or even that one must be fully evaluated before the other.

Comment: It is not a compiler bug. It is never a compiler bug.

Comment: Also, g++ and clang are well-established compilers.  There is no chance that they have a "bug" in such tiny, simple code.  If they had such a bug in a toy program like this, thousands of programmers and companies would have reported it.  Thus always assume your program is going into undefined behavior land.

Comment: jakob stark, clang did gave warning but ran fine and i expected the result, but i did not expect what g++ did: myA *2 did first, now myA = 6, myA++: A::temp =6, myA=7, y =13

Comment: @AmmarTamimi *but i did not expect what g++ did* -- I bought a rope that the manufacturer says can only hold 500 pounds.  I put 600 pounds on the rope, and it didn't break.  I bought another rope that can hold only 500 pounds, but it broke immediately when I tried to hold up 600 pounds.  Who is at fault, the rope, or you for not following the instructions and warnings?

Comment: @AmmarTamimi It is your expectations that are wrong, not the compilers. Why do you think that what you expect must be right?

Comment: @AmmarTamimi by the way GCC also gives you a warning if you enable warnings with the `-Wall` flag (which you really should do).

Comment: what I see is inconsistent behavior of g++ part between the two expression: y = myINT++ + myINT*2;   and y = myA++ + myA*2;

Comment: To be a bit picky, the `int` code has undefined behaviour; the behaviour of the `A` code is not undefined, but its result is unspecified and depends on the order of evaluation of `myA++` and `myA`.

Comment: On a side note, mutating `*` and `+` operators are Evil. Just don't.

Comment: @AmmarTamimi Also, running your program on Visual C++ 2019, the output is `9 4 13 7`.  Now you have 3 different compilers and 3 different results.

Comment: Please don't define `*` and `+` as if they were `*=` and `+=`.

Comment: Please note that _"...undefined behavior - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program..."_ _"...Compilers are __not__ required to diagnose undefined behavior..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub  The requirement is on the programmer to know the rules of C++, which is kind of tough. IIRC someone did a review of the Standard and came up with nearly 100 cases where UB is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: I thought unary operator has higher precedence such as myA++, over binary operator such as myA* 2, so myA++ goes first in expression left to right?!

Comment: @AmmarTamimi Why are you still trying to figure out "unspecified behavior"?  I mentioned that Visual C++ gives another set of answers.  I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if differing compiler settings yielded different results on the same compiler.

Comment: @AmmarTamimi *so myA++ goes first in expression left to right?!* -- The compiler is free to evaluate either side of the `+` first -- the order is unspecified.

Comment: Operator precedence has nothing to do with what gets executed first. Operator precedence is about which operators get which operands.